# Device to device Communication via IOT hub of Azure

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub-device-management

Hello community,
                 I have been implementing bi-directional communication between Raspberry pi and esp32 via Azure. Pi and ESP32 has been connected to IOT hub. I have been stuck in the function app to Cosmos DB implementation. When ever I include cosmos DB at the output , I am getting "503 service unavailable" error. The screenshot is shared. If this succeeds ,I want to design a function app that can control my ESP32 with the data based on sensor values of Pi. But I don't have much idea on how it can be implemented. So ,I have two problems here regarding implementation of function app of azure. Usage of function app is being difficult for me so far.

Comment: Unfortunately, as written, this is a fairly broad question, since there are many ways to process inbound messages, and then send outbound messages. You said you tried using function apps but it wasn't a good approach. Perhaps edit your question to illustrated what you tried, what worked, what didn't, what issues you ran into, etc.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I have edited the question, hope this is more clear  than previous one.